# Determine differences between two Strings, for use in undo/redo feature

Tags: java, strings, android

I made a library that adds undo/redo functionality to `EditText` widgets in Android. It came from problem I had building text-editing apps that deal with large (1,000words plus) volumes of text, and the performance problems I came across using [some pre-existing solutions](http://credentiality-android-scripting.googlecode.com/hg/android/ScriptingLayerForAndroid/src/com/googlecode/android_scripting/activity/ScriptEditor.java). Calling `setText()` with large amounts of text on [some of my low-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801232/edittext-performance-understanding-gpu-process-time-on-profile-gpu-rendering) devices would freeze the UI for several seconds, so saving all text on screen at various intervals and then using `setText()` during "undo" calls wasn't appropriate.

A large portion of what I've built relies on a `SubtractStrings` class, that compares two `String`s (an old one, representing the last time text was autosaved, and a new one, representing the latest save), and calculates important bits of information relating to the exact points where the two texts differ. This means that during an "undo" call, all that happens is the text that is changed is updated with a less expensive `insert()`, `replace()` or `delete()` call on `editText.getText()`.

As this is my first library for what seems to be a niche problem, and as I am self-taught in Android, I wanted to get some feedback on whether my approach was a good one, whether there were any obvious improvements I could make, general style etc. The code below works - I've tested this for a couple of days and it seems to give the correct results.

```
final class SubtractStrings implements Parcelable {

    private static final String TAG = "SubtractStrings";

    static final int ADDITION = 55023;
    static final int REPLACEMENT = ADDITION + 1;
    static final int DELETION = REPLACEMENT + 1;
    static final int UNCHANGED = DELETION + 1;

    private final char[] mOldText, mNewText;
    private final char[] mOldTextReversed, mNewTextReversed;

    private int firstDeviation, lastDeviation, tempReverseDeviation;
    private int lastDeviationOldText, lastDeviationNewText;
    private int deviationType;
    private int shortestLength, longestLength;

    private final boolean isNewTextLonger, isTextLengthEqual;

    public SubtractStrings(String oldString, String newString) {

        mOldText = oldString.toCharArray();
        mNewText = newString.toCharArray();

        mOldTextReversed = reverseCharArray(mOldText);
        mNewTextReversed = reverseCharArray(mNewText);

        shortestLength = findShortestLength(mOldText, mNewText);
        longestLength = findLongestLength(mOldText, mNewText);

        isNewTextLonger = (mNewText.length > mOldText.length);
        isTextLengthEqual = (mNewText.length == mOldText.length);

        findDeviations();
    }

    protected SubtractStrings(Parcel in) {
        mOldText = in.createCharArray();
        mNewText = in.createCharArray();
        mOldTextReversed = in.createCharArray();
        mNewTextReversed = in.createCharArray();
        firstDeviation = in.readInt();
        lastDeviation = in.readInt();
        tempReverseDeviation = in.readInt();
        lastDeviationOldText = in.readInt();
        lastDeviationNewText = in.readInt();
        deviationType = in.readInt();
        shortestLength = in.readInt();
        longestLength = in.readInt();
        isNewTextLonger = in.readByte() != 0;
        isTextLengthEqual = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<SubtractStrings> CREATOR = new Creator<SubtractStrings>() {
        @Override
        public SubtractStrings createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SubtractStrings(in);
        }

        @Override
        public SubtractStrings[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SubtractStrings[size];
        }
    };

    private void findDeviations() {
        //check equality. If equal, exit early
        if (checkCharArraysEqual()) {
            return;
        }
        //populate first deviation
        findFirstDeviation();
        //find last deviation
        findLastDeviation();
        //Calculate offset that may occur on last deviation
        findLastDeviationOffset();
        //Find deviation type (Add, Delete, Replace)
        findDeviationType();
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether old and new text are equal. If they are equal, then no deviations are recorded.
     * @return True if new and old text are equal.
     */
    private boolean checkCharArraysEqual() {
        if (Arrays.equals(mOldText, mNewText)) {
            firstDeviation = lastDeviation = 0;
            deviationType = UNCHANGED;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the first point of deviation between old and new text, by comparing each individual
     * char from beginning to end.
     *
     * @see #getFirstDeviation()
     */
    private void findFirstDeviation() {

        for (int i = 0; i < shortestLength; i++) {
            if (mOldText[i] != mNewText[i]) {
                firstDeviation = i;
                return;
            }
        }

        firstDeviation = shortestLength;

    }

    /**
     * Calculates the last point of deviation by reversing old and new text, and repeating the same
     * process as {@link #findFirstDeviation()}. Different values are assigned for old and new text
     * in order to effectively calculate what has changed between the two. This is especially
     * relevant when text is replaced.
     *
     * Under certain circumstances, running both this and {@link #findFirstDeviation()} alone will
     * produce incorrect results, especially when words are duplicated. For example:
     *
     * <pre>
     *     {@code
     *     int firstDeviation, lastDeviation;
     *
     *     char[] mOldText = new String("one").toCharArray();
     *     char[] mNewText = new String("one one").toCharArray();
     *
     *     findFirstDeviation();
     *     findLastDeviation();
     *
     *     String output = new String(mNewText).subString(firstDeviation, lastDeviation);
     *
     *     //firstDeviation will equal 3, last deviation 4, and "output" will be " ".
     *     }
     * </pre>
     *
     * This is because the first deviation comes after the first "e", at index 3, yet when the
     * arrays are reversed, the "e" at the end of "one" in mOldText shifts to index 0. It is
     * effectively counted twice:
     *
     * <pre>
     *     {@code
     *     char[] mOldText = new char[]{ 'o', 'n', 'e' }
     *     char[] mNewText = new char[]{ 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e' };
     *
     *     mOldTextReversed = new char[]{ 'e', 'n', 'o' };
     *     mNewTextReversed = new char[]{ 'e', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'o'};
     *     }
     * </pre>
     *
     * lastDeviation values are adjusted in {@link #findLastDeviationOffset()} to account for such
     * situations.
     *
     * @see #getLastDeviation()
     *
     */
    private void findLastDeviation() {

        for (int i = 0; i < shortestLength; i++) {
            if (mOldTextReversed[i] != mNewTextReversed[i]) {
                tempReverseDeviation = i;
                lastDeviationNewText = (isNewTextLonger) ? (longestLength - i) : (shortestLength - i);
                lastDeviationOldText = (isNewTextLonger) ? (shortestLength - i) : (longestLength - i);
                lastDeviation = (isNewTextLonger) ? lastDeviationNewText : lastDeviationOldText;
                return;
            }
        }

        tempReverseDeviation = shortestLength;
        lastDeviation = (longestLength - shortestLength);
        lastDeviationNewText = (isNewTextLonger) ? (longestLength - shortestLength) : shortestLength;
        lastDeviationOldText = (isNewTextLonger) ? shortestLength : (longestLength - shortestLength);

    }

    /**
     * Takes the {@link #lastDeviation} value adjusted in {@link #findLastDeviationOffsetSize()}, and
     * applies to {@link #lastDeviationNewText} and {@link #lastDeviationOldText}
     */
    private void findLastDeviationOffset() {

        int deviationOffset = findLastDeviationOffsetSize();
        int offsetValue = longestLength - shortestLength;

        lastDeviationNewText = (isNewTextLonger) ? deviationOffset : deviationOffset - offsetValue;
        lastDeviationOldText = (isNewTextLonger) ? deviationOffset - offsetValue : deviationOffset;

    }

    /**
     * Adjusts the last point at which the two char[] diverge, due to the reasons outlined in
     * {@link #findLastDeviation()}. This is achieved by calculating the difference in length between
     * the old and new text, and comparing each char from this final end point to the char at the
     * same position less the offset difference. If the same value is found, then the current
     * index is used to determine the true last deviation value. For example:
     *
     * <pre>
     *     {@code
     *     mOldTextReversed = new char[]{ 'e', 'n', 'o' };
     *     mNewTextReversed = new char[]{ 'e', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'o'};
     *     }
     * </pre>
     *
     * In this case, the potential offset size (the length of the longest array subtracted from the
     * shortest) is {@code(7 - 3) = 4}. Thus, the char at index [4] of the longest array, which is
     * 'e', is compared to the char at index[0] (4 - (potentialOffsetSize of 4) = 0), which is also
     * 'e'. As the two values match, the final value assigned to {@link #lastDeviation} is
     * (length of the longest array - (current index - potential offset size)), which translates
     * to (7 - (4 - 0)) = 3.
     *
     * @return The adjusted last deviation value.
     */
    private int findLastDeviationOffsetSize() {

        final char[] longestArray = (isNewTextLonger) ? mNewTextReversed : mOldTextReversed;

        final int potentialOffsetSize = longestLength - shortestLength;

        boolean isOffsetWithinArrayBounds =
                ((tempReverseDeviation + potentialOffsetSize) < longestLength);

        final int maxValue = (isOffsetWithinArrayBounds)
                ? (tempReverseDeviation + potentialOffsetSize)
                : longestLength;

        final int reverseDeviation = (tempReverseDeviation < potentialOffsetSize)
                ? potentialOffsetSize
                : tempReverseDeviation;

        for (int i = reverseDeviation; i < maxValue; i++) {

            if (longestArray[i] == longestArray[i - reverseDeviation]) {
                return (longestLength - (i - reverseDeviation));
            }

        }

        if (longestLength == mNewText.length) {
            isOffsetWithinArrayBounds = ((lastDeviationNewText < firstDeviation));
            lastDeviation = (isOffsetWithinArrayBounds)
                    ? (lastDeviationNewText + potentialOffsetSize)
                    : lastDeviationNewText;
            return lastDeviation;
        } else {
            isOffsetWithinArrayBounds = ((lastDeviationOldText < firstDeviation));
            lastDeviationOldText = (isOffsetWithinArrayBounds)
                    ? (lastDeviationNewText + potentialOffsetSize)
                    : lastDeviationNewText;
            return lastDeviation;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Populates the {@link #deviationType} field with one of three constant values,
     * representing an ADDITION of text, from old to new, with no text from old replaced. DELETION,
     * showing a removal of text from old to new, in which no text was replaced, and a REPLACEMENT,
     * in which text has been either added or removed from old to new, and overwritten the old text
     * in part or in its entirety. For example:
     *
     * <b>ADDITION:</b> The difference between "one" and "one two".
     *
     * <b>DELETION:</b> The difference between "one two" and "one".
     *
     * <b>REPLACEMENT:</b> The difference between "one" and "two".
     *
     * @see #getDeviationType()
     */
    private void findDeviationType() {

        if (isNewTextLonger) {
            deviationType = (isArrayEqualWithOmission(mNewText, mOldText, firstDeviation, lastDeviationNewText))
                    ? ADDITION
                    : REPLACEMENT;
        } else if(isTextLengthEqual) {
            deviationType = REPLACEMENT;
        } else {
            deviationType = (isArrayEqualWithOmission(mNewText, mOldText, firstDeviation, lastDeviationOldText))
                    ? DELETION
                    : REPLACEMENT;
        }

    }

    private static int findShortestLength(char[] arrOne, char[] arrTwo) {

        return Math.min(arrOne.length, arrTwo.length);

    }

    private static int findLongestLength(char[] arrOne, char[] arrTwo) {

        return Math.max(arrOne.length, arrTwo.length);

    }

    private static char[] reverseCharArray(char[] input){

        char[] output = input.clone();
        char temp;
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = (output.length - 1); i >= (output.length/2); i--) {
            temp = input[i];
            output[i] = input[index];
            output[index] = temp;
            index++;
        }

        return output;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether the contents of two arrays are equal, after a section from one array is
     * removed.
     *
     * Used to determine whether text has been replaced, or added to/deleted from.
     *
     * @param arrOne First array
     * @param arrTwo Second array
     * @param omissionStart Start index of section to remove from the longer or arrOne and arrTwo.
     * @param omissionEnd End index of section to remove.
     * @return True if both arrOne and arrTwo are equal after section specified in omissionStart
     * and omissionEnd is removed from the longer of the two.
     *
     * @see #findDeviationType()
     */
    private static boolean isArrayEqualWithOmission(char[] arrOne, char[] arrTwo, int omissionStart, int omissionEnd) {

        final boolean isArrOneLonger = (arrOne.length > arrTwo.length);

        final char[] arrOneCopy = (isArrOneLonger)
                ? omitCharArrayEntriesAtIndexes(arrOne.clone(), omissionStart, omissionEnd)
                : arrOne.clone();

        final char[] arrTwoCopy = (!isArrOneLonger)
                ? omitCharArrayEntriesAtIndexes(arrTwo.clone(), omissionStart, omissionEnd)
                : arrTwo.clone();

        return Arrays.equals(arrOneCopy, arrTwoCopy);

    }

    /**
     * Removes the section between the index positions at omissionStart and omissionEnd from arr.
     * @param arr Input array
     * @param omissionStart Start index of section to remove.
     * @param omissionEnd End index of section to remove.
     * @return The array arr, less the section between omissionStart and omissionEnd.
     */
    private static char[] omitCharArrayEntriesAtIndexes(char[] arr, int omissionStart, int omissionEnd) {

        final int omissionLength = omissionEnd - omissionStart;
        char[] output = new char[arr.length - omissionLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i < omissionStart) {
                output[i] = arr[i];
            } else if (i >= omissionEnd) {
                output[i - omissionLength] = arr[i];
            }

        }

        return output;

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return int[] containing first and last deviation points
     */
    public int[] getDeviations() {
        return new int[] { firstDeviation, lastDeviation };
    }

    public int[] getDeviationsNewText() {
        return new int[] { firstDeviation, lastDeviationNewText };
    }

    public int[] getDeviationsOldText() {
        return new int[] { firstDeviation, lastDeviationOldText };
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return First deviation
     */
    public int getFirstDeviation() {
        return  firstDeviation;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Last deviation, after adjustments with {@link #findLastDeviationOffset()}
     */
    public int getLastDeviation() {
        return  lastDeviation;
    }

    public int getLastDeviationOldText() {
        return lastDeviationOldText;
    }

    public int getLastDeviationNewText() {
        return lastDeviationNewText;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Deviation type, in the form of an int value. For a String representation, use
     * {@link #getDeviationTypeAsString()}
     */
    public int getDeviationType() {
        return deviationType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Deviation type as String representing whether text has been added, deleted, replaced
     * or unchanged between old and new.
     */
    public String getDeviationTypeAsString() {

        switch (deviationType) {
            case ADDITION:
                return "Addition";
            case DELETION:
                return "Deletion";
            case REPLACEMENT:
                return "Replacement";
            case UNCHANGED:
                return "Unchanged";
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect deviationType");

    }

    /**
     * Converts {@code int} value returned by {@link #getDeviationType()} to {@link String}
     * representation.
     * @param deviationType
     * @return String representation of argument if argument is valid. Otherwise, {@code null}
     */
    public static final String valueOfDeviation(int deviationType) {

        switch (deviationType) {
            case ADDITION:
                return "Addition";
            case DELETION:
                return "Deletion";
            case REPLACEMENT:
                return "Replacement";
            case UNCHANGED:
                return "Unchanged";
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return If text has been added or replaced, returns a substring of the new text that has
     * been altered in respect to old text.
     */
    public String getAlteredText() {

        switch (deviationType) {
            case ADDITION:
            case REPLACEMENT:
                return new String(mNewText).substring(firstDeviation, lastDeviationNewText);
        }

        return "";
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return If text has been deleted or replaced, returns a substring of the old text that has
     * been removed or overwritten.
     */
    public String getReplacedText() {

        switch (deviationType) {
            case DELETION:
            case REPLACEMENT:
                return new String(mOldText).substring(firstDeviation, lastDeviationOldText);
        }

        return "";

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeCharArray(mOldText);
        dest.writeCharArray(mNewText);
        dest.writeCharArray(mOldTextReversed);
        dest.writeCharArray(mNewTextReversed);
        dest.writeInt(firstDeviation);
        dest.writeInt(lastDeviation);
        dest.writeInt(tempReverseDeviation);
        dest.writeInt(lastDeviationOldText);
        dest.writeInt(lastDeviationNewText);
        dest.writeInt(deviationType);
        dest.writeInt(shortestLength);
        dest.writeInt(longestLength);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (isNewTextLonger ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeByte((byte) (isTextLengthEqual ? 1 : 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on Code Review! You've written a very fine first question, I'm sure you'll get good reviews! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are my suggestions:

1. separate the string comparison algorithm from the technology (Parcelable).
   This will help you to test your algorithm without the burden of technology and increases resusability in other contexts.
2. Use Enums instead of int (map as early as possible to Enum --> SubtractStrings(Parcel in), and map as late as possible to int --> writeToParcel()). Maybe you hold the int within the Enum.
   getDeviationTypeAsString() will then simply return enum.toString(), no exception necessary.
3. If you use int then do not make the constants depend on each other.
4. for methods with a return value only use ONE return statement at the END. Avoid using break or continue in loops.
   This will help to have IDE supported refactorings like "extract method"
5. for methods without a return value find a solution without a return statement. Avoid using break or continue in loops.
   This will help to support refactorings like "extract method"
6. remove valueOfDeviation() it is redundant to getDeviationTypeAsString()
7. return an Enum UNKNOWN instead of null, if it's really necessary. I don't think that you need an exception or null, because you can ALWAYS calculate deviations null or an exception would be unexpected to any other developer.
8. reduce state. create delegation methods to origin for shortestLength, longestLength, isNewTextLonger, isTextLengthEqual
9. do not pass shortestLength, longestLength, isNewTextLonger, isTextLengthEqual to Parcelable and do not read them from Parcelable, calculate it instead
10. break up findLastDeviationOffsetSize() into smaller pieces
11. do not provide getters for things getting calculated. provide only ONE result method with a composed Object with the proper Enum, text and the other metrics the client may be interested in (firstDeviation, lastDeviation, lastDeviationOldText, lastDeviationNewText): Result getResult(). this hides internal state and makes the solution more functional.
12. if unchanged, then return UNCHANGED and the old text (or the new text), not an empty String
13. After 11. delay findDeviations() until it's really necessary (when the result is demanded)
14. let polymorphism of the Enum work for you: provide a method String getDeviation(mOldText, mNewText, firstDeviation, lastDeviationOldText)
15. avoid inline declaration of variables of the same type. It's bothersome to separate them again if a type changes.
16. avoid calculating more than one value within one method. Examples: checkCharArraysEqual() is returning boolean and setting the state of two vars. findLastDeviation() is changing state of four vars.
17. Evaluate every "cached" value lazy and create a lazy getter and use it everwhere. So you become independent of the call order in findDeviations(). findDeviations() should be obsolete then and all should be implicit dependent from "Result getResult()". Example: refactor "void findFirstDeviation()" to int getFirstDeviation(). Another advantage is: "int" becomes part of the signature so you see the type at once.
18. Introduce "adjustedLastDeviationNewText" and do not manipulate lastDeviationNewText once it was calculated. This makes clear that lastDeviationNewText is not the final result.
19. try to degenerate the construtor to assign the parameters only, without calculation.
20. Extract isArrayEqualWithOmission(...), omitCharArrayEntriesAtIndexes(...), reverseCharArray(...) to other classes and make them public. They are producing no side effect so it is safe. Furthermore the methods can be tested then.
21. do not use *.clone() in reverseCharArray(...). It does more than necessary and confuses the reader about the intention. You want to have an array of the same size but an array with the same elements is not needed.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.